# Is dispalcement current produced in inductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

As we know in case of capacitor, changing electric field inside it produces a current which is called a displacement current (Amperes law modified by Maxwell). In case of inductor, is there any production of current like displacement current due to change of magnetic field?

Comment: assume a time-harmonic case, if the frequency $f$ is high enough so that $\lambda = c/f << \mathcal {l_s} ~ $ length of the solenoid, then the solenoid will radiate and $\epsilon_0 \omega \mathbf{E}$ will be the resulting displacement current density in vacuum.